# Why is my JSON model not parsing not working for List of string only?

Tags: c#, json, model, json.net

I have the following JSON data structure stored in a file, I have made a JSON data model in C# using the following tool [JsonToCsharp](https://jsontocsharp.olsh.me/). Usually, this tool is perfect and makes me awesome data models, but this time, for an unknown reason, each time I parse the JSON content, all string lists are null.

```
{
  "Targets": [
    {
      "Name": "myTarget",
      "Sharpmakes": [
        {
          "Name": "myTarget_v01",
          "Dest": "/myTarget/folder/destination"
        }
      ],
      "Includes": [
        "default_files" // <= This will always be null
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "default_files",
      "Directories": [
        {
          "Source": "/default/utils",
          "Dest": "/utils",
          "Includes": [ "*.bat", "*.ini", "*.txt", "*.xml", "*.json" ]   // <= This will always be null 
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

This is the code I am using for parsing my JSON:

```
try
{
    var jsonContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(packageDefinitionJsonConfigPath);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Package>(jsonContent);
 }
 catch (Exception exception)
 {
     Log.Error($"Could not parse the json \n\n{packageDefinitionJsonConfigPath}");
     throw exception;
 }
```

Nothing is quite special about this code snippet, it's a simple NewtonSoft JSON parse.

And here are my generated models that JsonToCsharp gave me, (which looks just fine)...

```
[JsonObject]
public class Package
{
    [JsonProperty("Targets")]
    public List<Target> Targets { get; set; }
}

public class Sharpmake
{

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Excludes")]
    public IList<string> Excludes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Dest")]
    public string Dest { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Includes")]
    public IList<string> Includes { get; set; }
}

public class File
{

    [JsonProperty("Source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Dest")]
    public string Dest { get; set; }
}

public class Directory
{

    [JsonProperty("Source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Dest")]
    public string Dest { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Includes")]
    public IList<string> Includes { get; set; }
}

public class Target
{

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sharpmakes")]
    public IList<Sharpmake> Sharpmakes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Includes")]
    public IList<string> Includes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Files")]
    public IList<File> Files { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Directories")]
    public IList<Directory> Directories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("Targets")]
    public IList<Target> Targets { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea **why my model could work just fine for everything except for my string lists?** There nothing out of the extraordinary in this code snippet, so I'm really clueless here...

Comment: What you mean under empty? Initialized but contains no elements?

Comment: I will correct my question, it's always null

Comment: What is `Package`?

Comment: You are deserializing to `Package`, but this is not included in the class definitions you posted.  Should that be `RootObject` instead?

Comment: Also, the JSON you posted seems to be just a fragment.  Can you post a well-formed sample which matches your model completely?  A fragment is not so helpful when trying to diagnose deserialization problems.  In fact, it would be best if you could provide a [mcve] we could compile and run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I've updated the code snippets, I'll also try to update my package for NewtonSoft.Json, I am using 12.0.1 which is almost the latest

Answer (score 1):

Updating my package to the latest version of Json.Net (12.0.2) seems to have fixed the issue

That would match with the release notes fixes

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.2